# .htaccess forward domain except some directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, forward

I want to forward almost all content of mydomain.com to mydomain.somewhereelse.com But I want that www.mydomain.com/mail and www.mydomain.com/stats are not forwarded to the new address.

How should I do this? Is there an IF ELSE solution?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^mail squirrelmail/src/login.php [R,NC]
RewriteRule  ^(.*)  http://new.example.com/$1
```

Above does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as very first rule below `RewriteBase` line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^(mail|stats) http://mydomain.somewhereelse.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=302]
```